# Sylius install: cannot rename

Tags: php, permissions, sylius

I'm a beginner in PHP and other stuff and I have problem with Sylius (for symfony2) installation. 
I used `XAMP` and windows 7.
After the command

```
$ php app/console sylius:install
```

in step 2 of 4 i got fatal error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException' with message "Cannot rename "C:\Users\xyz\sylius\app\cache\de_" to "C:\Users\xyz\sylius\app\cache\dev".
in C:\Users\xyz\sylius\sylius\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystemphp:262.
```

I have no idea what to do next. I tried `cache:clear` and normal delete cache folder but it's still doesn't work.
Any ideas?
I'm a beginner so if you could explain it I would be grateful.
PHP is really hard for me... :(

Comment: that's not a symfony problem. that's a permissions/path problem.

Comment: Yes, as @MarcB say, that is a permission error, you can set public permission on folder

Comment: But how can i do it?

Comment: Windows doesn't have the same permission issues you'd get on Unix systems. The cause is probably either the target exists or that there is a file in the cache that is currently in use by PHP or something else.

Comment: @MrK can you raise this as a bug in https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues ?